# Can the definition of linear space be generalized as elements closed under addition and linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm totally new of learning linear algebra and I'm currently working on linear spaces and linear maps. I found that the scalar multiplication is also a linear map which can be noted as M(a + b) = M(a) + M(b).

The question is can I generalize that linear space is the algebra which is closed under addition and linear maps under field F instead of talking about the scalar operation? Can the linear space be constructed in this way?

Comment: Yea, that works, I think?

Comment: What do you mean by "closed under linear maps under field $F$"? What would be an example of something not being closed under linear maps? Welcome to math.se btw.

Comment: @Babelfish Thanks for reply. I mean can linear spaces have the property that elements in the space is closed under any map M satisfying M(a+b)=M(a)+M(b)? Precisely, for a space S, if a in S, then M(a) is also in S.

Comment: @Comcx Can you make a counterexample? If $V$ is your set, where would $M$ be a map to and from? You need another space, since if $M\colon V\to V$, then of course all elements in $V$ are closed under $M$.

Comment: @Babelfish Thanks! Yes, that's exactly what I mean! M: V -> V. But can I define linear space only with addition and linear maps without talking about scalars?

Comment: @Babelfish I just found a special example. Consider complex field C, map M: C -> C, i.e. M(a+bi) = a-bi. M(x+y) = M(x)+M(y), but fails to satisfy cM(x) = M(cx), which I considered can be omitted if linear space can be constructed in a new way. So I now suppose my point is not correct.

Comment: @Don Thousand Thanks! I just found a special example. Consider complex field C, map M: C -> C, i.e. M(a+bi) = a-bi. M(x+y) = M(x)+M(y), but fails to satisfy cM(x) = M(cx), which I considered can be omitted if linear space can be constructed in a new way. So I now suppose my point is not correct.

Comment: You can define an algebra $A$ over $\mathbb F$ as $(A,\mathbb F,h)$, where $A$ is a ring, $\mathbb F$ a field, and $h\colon \mathbb F\to Z(A)$ a ring homomorphism to the center of $A$. There is no explicit mention of scalars here; for $(\sigma,a)\in \mathbb F\times A$ scalar multiplication is given by $(\sigma,a)\mapsto h(\sigma)a$.

Comment: @Comcx, I still don't understand what you mean by "closed under a linear map". Your map $M$, the complex conjugation, is not $\mathbb C$-linear. But $\mathbb C$ is of course closed under application of $M$, as if $v\in \mathbb C$, then also $M(v)\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @Babelfish Thanks for your patience. I think I didn't describe my question rigorously. I now think that my definition is too large and this is not linear algebra any more.

Comment: @Goran Malic Thanks! I'm still studying abstract algebra, this view helps me a lot!